# How can i send a value from one component to another in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I set a value in one component and i want to send it another component. I do the following
So in component B i set the value

```
 const getvalue = (event) => {                
    const myvalue = "Test value"                
}

function goToPage(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}
    const gotopage = (event) => {
    goToPage('/ComponentA')        
};
```

I want to call component A , i do with calling gotopage in component B and this goes to component A , but how can i send "myvalue" with it and bind to a property on the component A page ?

But how can i send the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your project is setup you need to either use some sort of centralized state management (context, redux) to store the value or pass the data through url params

```
goToPage(`/ComponentA?myValue=${myValue}`)
```